# Mechanism of reaction between triphenylmethanol and acetyl chloride

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I am reading an old method for making triphenylchloromethane ([*Org. Synth.* **1943**, *23*, 100](http://orgsyn.org/demo.aspx?prep=CV3P0841)):

$\hspace{30 mm}$[image: Reaction]

When I draw out the structures of the molecules, I see this:

[image]

But the $\mathrm{S_N1}$ mechanism doesn't make sense to me since $\ce{OH-}$ is a bad leaving group, and there is nothing to protonate it.

Comment: SN1 reactions are based on the stability of carbocation (R+), whereas SN2 reactions are based on the steric hinderance in R group.

Answer (score 6):

I find it unlikely that the substitution proceeds via the hydroxyl group directly leaving. If there is any evidence that this reaction proceeds via direct $\mathrm{S_N1}$ of $\ce{OH-}$ by $\ce{Cl-}$, I would be very interested to see it. When an alcohol and an acyl chloride are mixed, I think it is much more probable that they will initially form the ester via nucleophilic acyl substitution:

$\hspace{27 mm}$[image: Acyl substitution]

---

Presumably, this ester is rather unstable because of steric repulsions between the three phenyl groups and the ester group. So now, the $\ce{-OAc}$ group ($\ce{Ac} = \ce{COCH3}$) can leave as a relatively stable carboxylate ion to give the resonance-stabilised carbocation:

$\hspace{35 mm}$[image: SN1]

The carbocation is then intercepted by chloride ions that were formed earlier to give the product you want. So, the second part of the reaction is a $\mathrm{S_N1}$ substitution of $\ce{OAc-}$ by $\ce{Cl-}$.

$\ce{OAc-}$ ($\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{aH} = 4.76$) is a much better leaving group than $\ce{OH-}$ ($\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{aH} = 15.7$).

---

There is another pathway possible, since $\ce{HCl}$ is formed from the initial reaction of the alcohol with the acyl chloride. If $\ce{HCl}$ is present in appreciable quantities, it can protonate the original alcohol and you could perhaps have a direct $\mathrm{S_N1}$ of $\ce{H2O}$ by $\ce{Cl-}$.

$\hspace{10 mm}$[image: SN1]

Comment: It all came back to me!  Thank you very much for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the hydroxide is a bad leaving group but look the structure if the hydroxide ion leave. It's a triphenyl cation! It's very stable carbocation (very high mesomeric effect). Then the reactive hydroxide react with acyl chloride and liberate Cl- that react with phenyl cation.